# Stop webview from loading and return to previous page

Tags: android, webview

I want to stop webview from loading a url when its starts with google.com from example and return back to default page[1. page].

In my webview client below it is not returning back to first page thougth the condition in should override method is good.

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                // view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rlChargement.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                progresswheel.spin();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                System.out.println("BROWSER URL : "+url);
                //Recherche sans filtre
                if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("http://www.google.com")){
                    System.out.println("INVALID");
                    web.clearCache(true);
                    ActToast.message="error message";
                    startActivity(new Intent(me, ActToast.class));
                    rlChargement.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    progresswheel.stopSpinning();
                    view.stopLoading();
                    web.clearHistory();
                }

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                // animate(view);
                // view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rlChargement.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progresswheel.stopSpinning();
            }
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/onreceivingerror.html");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to override WebView.goBack():

```
  @Override
  public void goBack() {
    WebBackForwardList temp = copyBackForwardList();
    for (int i=0; i<temp.getSize(); i++) {
      WebHistoryItem item = temp.getItemAtIndex(i);
      // do whatever you want here...
    }

    // do whatever you want here...
    super.goBack();
  }
```